# Return value of last populated cell in variable range

Tags: excel, dynamic

Into column D, I'd like to copy the value from the last cell with data in columns E up until the column with the header "DETAIL". There might be anywhere from 2 to 15 columns from E until the column with that header, so that's where I'm stuck. So to be clear, an example:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    DETAIL
1   x    x    x         a    b    c    d    x
2   x    x    x                             x
3   x    x    x         c    b    a         x
3   x    x    x         d    c              x
```

Should fill column D like so:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    DETAIL
1   x    x    x    d    a    b    c    d    x
2   x    x    x                             x
3   x    x    x    a    c    b    a         x
3   x    x    x    c    d    c              x
```

I don't mind handling this with a formula (which I couldn't come up with) or programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dynamic named range by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the Name Manager, click New, name the range something (I chose `MyRange`) and then use this formula to define it (Note you may need to change the Sheet name):

```
=Sheet1!E2:INDEX(Sheet1!2:2,MATCH("Detail",Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1)
```

[image: tigeravatar dynamic named range for E2:"Detail"]

Then, in cell D2 and copied down, use this formula (I did not use `IFERROR` so that it would be backwards compatible):

```
=IF(COUNTA(MyRange),INDEX(MyRange,MATCH(REPT("z",255),MyRange)),"")
```

Here are the results (highlighted) using your provided sample data:

[image: Formula results]

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F2:T2,,MATCH("zzzzzz",F2:T2)),"")
```

in D2 and copied down to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^99,SEARCH("*",E1:H1),E1:H1),"")
```

`SEARCH("*",E1:H1)` returns a number when it matches any character and an error when the cell is blank. `LOOKUP` then returns the contents of the cells of the last number smaller than `9^99` in the array generated by `SEARCH`.

For example, in the first row, `SEARCH("*",E1:H1)` returns `{1,1,1,1}` so that `LOOKUP` returns the last 1, being `d`.

In the third row, `SEARCH("*",E3:H3)` returns `{1, 1, 1, #VALUE!}` and `LOOKUP` returns the last 1, which is `a` here.

This formula will work with numbers and text alike. The downside is that it is considered slower than [`INDEX`/`MATCH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921913/1578604). On the other hand, you can modify the `INDEX`/`MATCH` to work with numbers, or modify it to work for both but becomes an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E1:H1,,MATCH(1,SEARCH("*",E1:H1))),"")
```

[Works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise returns an empty cell with <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone]

Comment: The first formula works well if the range were always going to be E1:H1. The problem was that I may have any number of columns after E before I got to the end of the applicable range. tigeravatar's method solved that problem. Thanks, though!

Comment: @SteveDouglas Oh, I didn't actually get that part! I thought the number of columns until the column 'Detail' was the same each time. Sorry about that ^^;